# Php - While [data] loop, $Post returning only first value

Tags: php, forms, post, mysqli, while-loop

I have this code, who retrieve AD account, mail, enabled from database.
Display is ok, and i'm adding an update button at each line (UpdateAccount) who permit updating account informations.

But when i'm submitting an update $Post values are always values from the first account (not the account i've selected).

**Exemple :**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Om7qa.jpg

**Problem :**

When i want to update the second account, $post send me data from the first account.

When i want to update the third account, $post send me data from the first account.

I think i need to pass a "$post ID" somewhere who contain the data i've selected, if you have any solution ...

**Code :**

```
<?php
$data = '';

# Retrieving account in database

$sql = "SELECT ".USERAD_ID.",".USERAD_ENABLED.",".USERAD_ACCOUNT.",".USERAD_EMAIL." FROM ".USERAD_TABLE."";
$mydb = new DB();
$result = $mydb->runQuery($sql);

# Template Column

echo "
<div class='col-sm-12'>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <div class='col-sm-1'><label class='BoxSmall col-sm-12 control-label'>ID</label></div>
            <div class='col-sm-2'><label class='BoxSmall col-sm-12 control-label'>Compte AD</label></div>
            <div class='col-sm-3'><label class='BoxSmall col-sm-12 control-label'>Adresse Mail</label></div>
            <div class='col-sm-1'><label class='BoxSmall col-sm-12 control-label'>Etat</label></div>
        </div>
</div>          

";

# While Account in $result, display data

while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$id     =   $data[USERAD_ID];
$account    =   $data[USERAD_ACCOUNT];
$email      =   $data[USERAD_EMAIL];
$enabled    =   $data[USERAD_ENABLED];

echo "  
    <div class='col-sm-12'>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <div class='col-sm-1'><input type='textsmall' required name='id' id='id' value='".$id."' '></div>
            <div class='col-sm-2'><input type='textsmall' required name='account' id='account' value='".$account."' '></div>
            <div class='col-sm-3'><input type='textsmall' required name='email' id='email' value='".$email."' '></div>
            <div class='col-sm-1'><input type='textsmall' required name='enabled' id='enabled' value='".$enabled."' '></div>

        <form id='updatead' role='form' method='post'>

                    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$id."'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='account' value='".$account."'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='email' value='".$email."'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='enabled' value='".$enabled."'>
        </form>

        <INPUT type='submit' class='form-updatead' value='updatead' name='submit'></INPUT>
        </div>
    </div>

";
}   

?>
```

Comment: put submit button inside form

Comment: If i do this, post is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple forms on a single page then your submit button just will post the first one by default. Considering removing the INPUT and use a button or div. Like this:

```
echo "  
<div class='col-sm-12'>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <div class='col-sm-1'><input type='textsmall' required name='id' id='id' value='".$id."' '></div>
        <div class='col-sm-2'><input type='textsmall' required name='account' id='account' value='".$account."' '></div>
        <div class='col-sm-3'><input type='textsmall' required name='email' id='email' value='".$email."' '></div>
        <div class='col-sm-1'><input type='textsmall' required name='enabled' id='enabled' value='".$enabled."' '></div>

    <form id='".$id."' role='form' method='post' action='/doSomething.php'>

                <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$id."'>
                <input type='hidden' name='account' value='".$account."'>
                <input type='hidden' name='email' value='".$email."'>
                <input type='hidden' name='enabled' value='".$enabled."'>
    </form>

    <button onclick='document.getElementById('".$id."').submit()'>Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
";
```

Note: I also added an "action='/doSomething.php'".

Comment: Copy / paste code error for the ", 1", this is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it's working perfectly.
Here is the final code working :

```
<?php

while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$id         =   $data[USERAD_ID];
$enabled    =   $data[USERAD_ENABLED];
$account    =   $data[USERAD_ACCOUNT];
$email      =   $data[USERAD_EMAIL];

echo "  
<div class='col-sm-12'  >
    <div class='form-group'>
        <form id='".$id."' role='form' method='post' action='./admin/permissionsform.php?page=updatead'>
            <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$id."'>
            <div class='col-sm-2'><input type='textsmall' required name='account' id='account' value='".$account."' style='width:75%'></div>
            <div class='col-sm-3'><input type='textsmall' required name='email' id='email' value='".$email."' style='width:75%'></div>
            <div class='col-sm-1'><input type='textsmall' required name='enabled' id='enabled' value='".$enabled."' style='width:75%'></div>
        </form>

        <button class='buttoneditsrv' onclick='document.getElementById(".$id.").submit()';window.location='./?view=list&search='>Mise &agrave jour</button>
    </div>
</div>
";
}
?>
```